# Scaling of force between cubes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, dimensional-analysis, scaling

I found an interesting problem online which has been confusing me for quite a while. Basically, two solid cubes of side length $a$ touch each other along one of their faces, and I am to find how many times greater the gravitational force is between two cubes of the same material with side length $ka$. I am told the answer is $k^4$, but I have no idea how to model this problem, and everything I’ve searched has either used computational methods or complicated integrals. Is there a simpler way of approaching this?

Comment: The mass of each cube has increased by $k^3$, the distance has increased by $k$. Consider how this affects the gravitation force, using Newton's law of gravitation.

Comment: @V.F. Why are we allowed to use Newton’s law of gravitation? Isn’t that for point masses? Or rather, is there a proof that it works for a cube?

Comment: Good question. Since the answer was already known, I just explained it. Chances are it could be proved, but probably not in a comment.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: The gravitational force between cubes with side length $a$ is

$${\bf F}(a) ~=~G\rho^2 \iiint_{[-a,0]\times[0,a]^2}\! d^3{\bf r} \iiint_{[0,a]^3}\! d^3{\bf r}^{\prime} \frac{{\bf r}-{\bf r}^{\prime}}{|{\bf r}-{\bf r}^{\prime}|^3}. $$

Now replace $a\to ka$. Try to look for a substitution of the integration variables.

Answer (score 0):

We can break each cube to a number of tiny cubes, and state that the total gravitational force between the cubes will be equal to the sum of gravitational forces between all possible pairs of tiny cubes.

If cubes are increased by a factor $k$, we can observe that the mass of each tiny cube should increase by $k^3$ and all the distances between tiny cube pairs should increase by $k$.

Keeping this in mind and using Newton's law of gravitation to express each tiny force before and after the scaling, we should find that the ratio between the sums of all these forces will be $k^4$, i.e., we can find the answer without actually calculating the sums or explicitly integrating all tiny forces.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand the physics scaling law, we can replace the complicated structure of two touching and paraxial cubes with two spheres that touch each other.  And suddenly it becomes very simple.

The gravitational force between two spheres (mass=m) of radius R that touch each other is $F=G*\frac{m^2}{4R^2}$.  Given a fixed mass density $\rho$ we can write $m=\rho\frac{4\pi}{3}R^3$.  Insert that into the force formula to obtain $F=G\cdot\frac{4\pi^2\rho^2}{9}\cdot R^4$

And so, the force indeed scales as $R^4$.